# How can I iterate over a dynamic IQueryable class, generated by LINQ?

Tags: linq, select, dynamic-data, iqueryable

I have a query like this:

```
var xx = tt.Select("new(t as Id)");
```

in which `Select` clause is from `System.Linq.Dynamic`.

The result in `xx` is a dynamic class which I need to iterate over its items like this:

```
foreach(var item in xx) {
    // do some thing with item.Id
}
```

What is the best way?

Comment: What language version? In C# 4.0, you can use the dynamic type

Comment: I'm in C# and using Entity Framework and LINQ. I have a dynamic query which a typeless collection as a result. When I try to iterate over it by Foreach statement, it raise an error about DynamicClass1.

Comment: Dear Andre, do you have a useful link for me to read about dynamic type?

Answer (score 3):

Try next code sample:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

var xx = tt.Select("new(t as Id)"); 

foreach(dynamic item in xx) { 
    // do some thing with item.Id 
}
```